# How to resolve an ambiguous dependency?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, dependency-injection, dependency-management

I have a ambiguous dependency in my group project. I don't want to reveal the code, because I'm not sure if I'm allowed to show it. That's why I want to give a abstract form where the problem is:

```
@ShiroSecured
@RequiresRoles({Role.ADMIN})
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class A{

    @Inject
    protected AbstractBean abstractBean; <-- Intellij shows me here 'Ambiguous dependency'
}


@Named
@ViewScoped
public class B extends A implements Serializable {
}

@Named
@ViewScoped
public class C extends A implements Serializable {
}
```

I kind of understand what the problem is, but I don't know how to fix it. I researched and there was something with deleting a `beans.xml` or using qualifiers?

Comment: What framework are you using to manage your beans?

Comment: you have probably multiple beans from the AbstractBean ( instance created from classes that extends AbstractBean) currently you are using the By Type injection , so you should manage this using Qualifier or By Name injection , try to read this : https://www.baeldung.com/spring-annotations-resource-inject-autowire